# How to get data that is the same type, but not including the one given in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to get a list of products similar to the one given (similar by given product type), but not including the one given.

I have 3 instances of beds in my database, so I want to get the other 2 instances of them, but not return the original 1, that in this case has the ID of 1.

Having looked at the documentation, I thought the below would work, but instead it's giving me a 500 internal error.

```
product_type = "Bed"
product_id = 1

client = MongoClient("...")
db = client.assignment

theId = db.products.find({"_id": {"$ne": product_id}})
theProd = db.products.find({"product_type": {"$eq": product_type}})

myCursor = db.products.find({"$and": [theId, theProd]})
list_cur = list(myCursor)
json_data = dumps(list_cur)
return json_data
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue, for anyone looking at this at a later date, I changed

```
theId = db.products.find({"_id": {"$ne": product_id}})
theProd = db.products.find({"product_type": {"$eq": product_type}})

myCursor = db.products.find({"$and": [theId, theProd]})
```

To

```
myCursor = db.products.find({"product_type": {"$eq": product_type}, "_id": {"$ne": product_id}})
```